# 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax - error in website after updgrading

Tags: mysql, sql

any body can help me with this please???

i upgraded my sql version to 5.6 and now i am having this error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY created desc LIMIT 0, 20' at line 4

```
SQL=SELECT * FROM actxp_bt_portfolio_comments 
WHERE published = 1 AND item_id = ORDER BY created desc LIMIT 0, 20
```

Comment: you're missing a value after `item_id =` - this is unrelated to any MySQL upgrade. This isn't a valid SQL statement in any MySQL version

Answer (score 0):

You missed to pass value to your `item_id` filter

```
SELECT * FROM actxp_bt_portfolio_comments 
WHERE published = 1 AND item_id = 'itemid'--Value missing here
ORDER BY created desc LIMIT 0, 20
```

Comment: thank you for your response hey thanks to all of you 

let me explain something now that all of you are saying that what i missing is a item id 

but the problem is this 

that is not a real link on my website 

this are links that are appearing on google webmaster tools

www.mywebsite.com/hangar-gpu/fmc-jet-power-plus.html

but the real link is this one 

/push-back-tractors/equitech-fmc-b250-tow-tractor.html

so my point is that it does not exist a item id for that 

does i miss understanding this?????? I am not an expert about sql can you advice how to fix

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning value to `item_id` in where clause.

```
SELECT * FROM actxp_bt_portfolio_comments 
WHERE published = 1 AND item_id =? 
ORDER BY created desc LIMIT 0, 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is invalid.  `item_id` does not have a value after the equals sign in the `WHERE` clause.